# Lost hardware volume controls after upgrade to 16.04 HWE Stack

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, hardware-enablement-stack

I am runnig Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell XPS 12 laptop.  After upgrading to the [16.04 Xenial HWE Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL), the following buttons on the casing stopped working:

- volume controls
- ‘windows button’ below the screen
  (this used to bring up the Dash)

I’m not bothered about the second point. 
But is there any way to bring back the volume controls?
Volume control via the keyboard (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd>/<kbd>f12</kbd>/<kbd>f13</kbd>) is still working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug with the kernel and should be reported using the command `ubuntu-bug linux`.